pdftex: uncopyable math symbols, \pdfglyphtounicode doesn't help
With TeX Live 2021 and pdftex, this MWE renders correctly but I cannot copy the ≪ sign out of the PDF.
\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{pdfapart=2,pdfaconformance=u,
  pdftitle={Test of Unicode mappings for certain math symbols}}

% Uncommenting the next line does not help.
%\pdfglyphtounicode{lessmuch}{226A}
\begin{document}

$1 \ll 10^{100}$

\end{document}

It can be selected and copied, but it pastes into a word processor as � and into a text editor as  ^\  (i.e. control character U+001c).
Decoding the PDF, I see the offending glyph is being displayed with
/F36 9.9626 Tf 7.749 0 Td [<1c>]TJ

/F36 is (a subset of) LMMathSymbols10-Regular, and its /Encoding object is
<<
  /Differences [
    28
    /lessmuch
  ]
  /Type /Encoding
>>

From which, it seems like the fix ought to be
\pdfglyphtounicode{lessmuch}{226A}

but in my testing that has no effect.
What do I need to do to make this character copyable correctly?  Note that lmodern is dictated by a journal, I can only change that if you are absolutely sure they won't notice.

looks ok in texlive 2022 and 2024, it copies as 1 ≪ 10100

Thanks for checking but I am stuck with 2021 (journal, again).

Easiest way seems to be just ignore it and make it render correctly in e.g. arXiv submission.

Actually it works on TeX live 2021 for me, it just doesn't work on TeX live 2020. I tried both \usepackage{cmap} and \input glyphtounicode   \pdfgentounicode=1 and it works in TeX live 2020 for me. Please test, if it works then I close as duplicate of pdftex - What are good ways to make pdflatex output copy-and-pasteable? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange .

You don't need \input glyphtounicode \pdfgentounicode=1 if you use \usepackage{cmap} @user202729. At least, it works for me with TL 2020 with just \usepackage{cmap}. As for you, TL 2021 works out-of-the-box, but probably you also updated during the 2021 release cycle and likely the journal didn't.

@UlrikeFischer I do not think this should be considered a duplicate.  "Why doesn't \pdfglyphtounicode fix this specific problem I'm having with copying from the PDF?" is not the same question as "Why can't I copy from the PDF with default settings?"

@zwol I didn't vote for a duplicate.

@UlrikeFischer Sorry, I mixed you up with user202729.

It turns out that \pdfglyphtounicode doesn't do anything (and therefore neither does \input glyphtounicode) unless you also have \pdfgentounicode=1 somewhere in your preamble.  I had thought that surely one of the PDF/A support packages I was using would turn that on, but no.
